# Truth value of a statement

Tags: proof-writing

I have a problem:

Let P be the statement " x $\in$ A and x $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$ "

statement: ($\forall$x)P $\Longrightarrow$ ($\exists$x)P

Is there a set A for which the truth value of the above statement is false? Explain.

My approach is:

The statement is only false when the antecedent is true and the consequent is false.

This is not possible because ...

Can someone help, please?

NOTE: Please forgive me : our assumption is that x is in the universal set R

Comment: @Prime Mover Hi, the answer is no. The empty set doesn't make the statement false. I don't know how to explain that.

Comment: Maybe because it's not true? How do you know "the answer is no"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first-order logic as presented in standard textbooks and standard introductory courses, the universe of discourse (i.e., the set of things that we talk about in our logical language) is non-empty. $\forall x\,P(x)$ means that $P(x)$ holds for every element of the universe and, as that universe is non-empty, $\exists x\,P(x)$ must hold if $\forall x\,P(x)$ does. So $(\forall x\,P(x)) \Rightarrow (\exists x\,P(x))$ is valid, for any predicate $P(x)$. In particular, $(\forall x\,(x \in A \land x \in \Bbb{Z})) \Rightarrow (\exists x\,(x \in A \land x \in \Bbb{Z}))$ is valid for any set $A$. So you correct in concluding that there is no set $A$ that makes this proposition false.

To address Prime Mover's concerns: if we are working in a first-order language that can talk about sets and set membership, then it is convenient to use relative quantifiers: i.e., to write $\forall x \in A\,Q(x)$ as an abbreviation for $\forall x \, (x \in A \Rightarrow Q(x))$ and to write $\exists x \in A, Q(x)$ as an abbreviation  for $\exists x(x \in A \land Q(x))$. Using this short-hand $\forall x \in \emptyset\,Q(x))$ is true and $\exists x \in \emptyset\,Q(x)$ is false, but this does not contradict the statement that $(\forall x\,P(x)) \Rightarrow (\exists x\, P(x))$, since when we expand the abbreviations, the matrix (body) of the two quantified subformulas are not the same.

Finally, I should say that there are logics that do not assume that quantification ranges over non-empty sets. Tennant's [Natural Logic](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Natural_Logic.html?id=rCCFQgAACAAJ&redir_esc=y) is one such system. [Martin-Löf type theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_type_theory) is another. Such logics are, in some sense, more precise than traditional first-order logic, but the extra precision has to be paid for by more onerous proof obligations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when $A \cap \mathbb Z$ is the empty set.

Then there are no such $x$ and so $(\forall x) P$ is true vacuously.

But as there exist no such $x$, there can exist no $x$ such that $P$ holds, so $(\exists x)P$ is false.

Comment: But $\forall x\,P$ doesn't mean the same as $\forall x \in A\,P$ for the given $P$.

Comment: @RobArthan Good call, I'm confused by the nature of the statement of the question. I'll rethink it.

Comment: It is a contingent sentence, depending on A and Z, it can be true and it can be false. If A is a subset of Z, then the antecendent is true, and the conclusion is true.  It is also true if when A and Z are both empty.

Comment: But $\mathbb Z$ is not empty because $\mathbb Z$ is the set of integers. I presume. OP does not give any information about the range of $x$, we have been left to guess. But the point is that "forall $x$ implies exists $x$" is true iff there are any $x$ to begin with. And if $x$ are such that $x \in A$ and $x \in \mathbb Z$ that means there has to be at least one element in $A \cap \mathbb Z$ in the first place. If not, then $(\forall x) P \implies (\exists x) P$ is false. If not, then can someone rewrite the question to clarify exactly what is meant? Domain of $x$, what means $\mathbb Z$ etc.?